# Is RabbitMQ more scalable than JMS outbound queue?

Tags: comparison, jms, scalability, rabbitmq

I want to know whether RabbitMQ is more scalable than other brokers or not?
If yes what are the specific reasons? If not how can we scale it up?

I am using rabbitmq for the first time with Spring framework.

Answer (score 1):

Even a single RabbitMQ broker is ridiculously fast.  A stock desktop machine can handle tens to hundreds of thousand of messages per second.

If one rabbit turns out to not be enough, RabbitMQ supports a form of [light-weight clustering](http://www.rabbitmq.com/clustering.html) that's designed specifically to improve scalability.  Basically, it allows you to create "logical" brokers that are made up of many physical brokers.

Comment: If i want to use multiple rabbitmq withtheir own database mnesia.Is mnesia is good or any external database like MS sql??

Comment: No.  Clustering is done internally by RabbitMQ.  HA Clustering, which is something completely different, can use Pacemaker.  Mnesia is as good as it gets.  The last time we tried, RabbitMQ + MySQL performance was fairly abysmal.